# There was no endpoint at http://localhost:8080/

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8.1

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 Store app. I needed connect to external database so I created WCF Service. It works fine when it is on my computer, but it crashes with error on my tablet device. 
I created a Windows Service via InstallUtil.exe and it works, I can go to page http://localhost:8080/ via browser. But when I start an application and wanted to receive some records it crashes with this error:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8080/DatabaseService that could accept message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

The thing is I did exactly the same thing on my computer and it works fine, but on my tablet it doesn't work.
Any help, please?

Comment: If it's a service it doesn't need IIS. Make sure the firewall isn't blocking it. That isn't a normally used port so Windows Firewall may be blocking it from external requests.

Comment: Should that URL not be more like `http://localhost:8080/DatabaseService.svc/endpointName`?

Comment: compman2408, I turned off the firewall

Comment: stuard, I created a WCF Service like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcmD1SfIayM&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVxEyaRMaMN_-qnDdNVGsL1&index=3&hd=1 (short: I created class library then I added WCF Service)

Answer (score 2):

I think I see the issue here. If you created the WCF Service on your computer then using http://localhost:8080 would work, but ONLY ON THE COMPUTER. However if the tablet tried accessing http://localhost:8080 it would not work. The tablet would have to substitute the IP address of the computer for 'localhost' in the address it tries to visit. For example, if the IP address of the computer is 192.168.1.23, the tablet would then have to visit http://192.168.1.23:8080.

The tablet won't work the with 'localhost' address as it doesn't have the WCF Service running on itself.

Comment: But this is exactly what suprises me, it has its own WCF Service running (I install this in Windows Service via InstallUtil.exe and I can see that service running in local Services. I did the same things to my computer and my tablet (of course I copied files like WindowsService project and Windows 8.1 AppPackage from my computer, because my tablet doesn't have Visual Studio).

Comment: @Shafter Oh. So you're using a tablet with the full Windows operating system and you installed the WCF service on it just like on the computer?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did. This application has to be working only on tablet, so it has to running this service as well.

Comment: If the service was installed on the tablet correctly, it seems as though it may not be running. I don't believe it is started automatically after it is installed so make sure it's actually running. Also adding the /DatabaseService to the URL shouldn't make a difference, but it may be worth testing without this if it worked without this on the desktop.

Comment: It is running. I added /DatabaseService and still nothing (now it shows localhost:8080/DatabaseService/DatabaseService in error)